# Scheduled email campaign with expressionengine

Tags: email, mailinglist, cron, campaignmonitor

I'd like to schedule the sending of emails, created with Firemail, to selected mailing lists.

I can see the postmaster module may do this, but the client has invested in Firemail and I have the mailing lists and campaigns set up, so I'd rather find another way to do this.

I've looked at Email Cron and ExpressionEngine cron, but I can't see a way to schedule emails to mailing lists.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Prob worth posting this question to the FireMail support forum on Devot-ee as I think that's where official support is provided for the module. :)

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/firemail/viewforum/508

Comment: Someone has already asked the same quiestion in the firemail support forum, the developer says he hasn't got time to create this functionality.